# Push a view controller after the issuing removeFromSuperview of another viewcontroller

Tags: pushviewcontroller

From my current view I called another view using addsubview and when I click ok I want to push  another view that will serve as my main view for the whole operation

call the first view:

```
dc=[[DriverConfirmation alloc]init ];
  [[dc view]setFrame:CGRectMake(186, 141, 616, 443)];
  [self view]addSubview:dc.view];
```

when I press ok button I removed it using

```
[[self view]removeFromSuperview];
```

but I cannot push the next view using this:

```
RouteManagement *rm=[[RouteManagement alloc]init];
    [self.parentViewController pushViewController:rm animated:NO];
    [rm release];
```

Thank you for any assistance you will give.

Comment: I suggest you add more tags for better visibility